# actionSubmit is not overriding the form's default action

Tags: forms, grails, grails-2.0

I'm running grails 2.2.4 under windows. My form's action is not taking the action specified under the actionSumit button. The code looks something like this:

```
<g:form controller="test" >
   <g:render template="form" />
</g:form>
```

The form template has a `<g:actionSubmit action="someaction" name="somebutton" />`

PS: There are many other <strike>forms</strike> buttons rendered under the form tag and a few of them use `<g:submitButton />` in several places. Is that causing the problem? I don't want to change all of them before I can be sure that this is working in my setup because that might mess up my application (or should I?).

Comment: Did I understand you correctly in that you are nesting forms within one another? If so, that's not going to work and will cause problems.

Comment: When he said “there are many other forms rendered under the form tag” I assumed he meant below the form in question, not inside of it.  Is that the case?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. These are not nested forms. There is, however, a mix of submitButton and actionSubmit inside the same form that I'm not too keen to clean up if it is not absolutely necessary.

Comment: I tried it again and it seems to work. I did not make any changes though (other than cleaning the project). The form tag, however, still shows the same default action for the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Nested forms are not valid , your should not have other forms inside your form

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. These are not nested forms. There is, however, a mix of submitButton and actionSubmit inside the same form that I'm not too keen to clean up if it is not absolutely necessary.